# How can I assign currencies to store view

Tags: magento2

How can I assign currencies to store view for example:

**The main currency of the page: euro**

- Store view Poland: I wanted to display only PLN
- Store view Poland: I wanted to display only EUR and USD.

How I can do ?

Comment: Two store views are the same?

Comment: Hi Khoa, thanks for your msg. yes, two store vievw is the same in Poland and English version.